# How to get only data without any metadata from cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to fetch only **data** from Cloud Firestore?

Right now I am fetching all documents from a collection, then I use loop to get the only data I saved already to Firestore as below:

```
const data = {};
const snap = await db.collection("rooms").where("ppl","array-contains", myUsername).get({source:"cache"});

for (let i = snap.size -1; i >= 0; i--){
    const {room} = snap.docs[i].data();

    const snapshot = await db.collection(`rooms/${room}/msgs`).orderBy("dt","desc").limit(50).get({source:"cache"});

    const tempMessages = [];

    if (len2 > 0) {
       for (let k = 0; k < len; k++) {
         tempMessages = [...tempMessages, snapshot.docs[k].data()];
       }
    }
    data = { ...data, [room]: tempMessages};
}
setRoomsMessages(data);
```

***Now what I want*** ???

I want to fetch **only and only array** of `snapshot.docs[k].data()` (**needed data**).

**Why** ? because I want to fetch `needed` data and then pass it to `state` directly. There is, I dont need for two nested loop I only loop the `rooms` and not for every `room messages`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here.  Why do you want to remove the loop?  There's nothing slow about it.  Most of the time spent in your query will be the round trip between the client and server.  You can't speed that up.

Comment: Because I have Two `Collections` one for `Users` and one for `Messages`, so therefore I have to have `two nested for`, think there is 50 `Users` and we fetch 50 `messages` for every `User` so then here we will face `50x50` loops, and there is I face with performance. for it takes 5 seconds to list messages even from `cache`.

Comment: I know that `snap.docs` is an array, but it has a lot of meta data. I want something like that, but with clean data I stored already to Firestore.

Comment: I think you might be trying to optimize before there is an actual performance problem.  Please edit your question to show more clearly what is slower than you'd like, and how you're benchmarking the code.  Your benchmarks should not include the time it takes to execute the query, since you can't control that.  I don't think you'll find any way to optimize a simple for loop in a significant way.

Comment: this question was already answered here [1], however, metadata charged by default on the queries to firestore, if you want to improve the performance on your app, you could optimize the structure on the data stored in firestore 


[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335738/how-to-get-documents-without-metadata-from-firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson, question edited please kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Also, you could try creating your constants outside from the loop in order to don't create a new constant in each iteration.

Comment: @HarifVelarde, I dont think the constant make slow the app